# Which scripture mention coronation of Rama on the very first day of Chaitra Navratri?

Tags: scripture, rama, festivals

The wiki [Gudi_Padwa#Significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudi_Padwa#Significance) says:

> Gudi Padva signifies the arrival of spring and to the reaping of Rabi crops. 
>   The festival is linked to the mythical day on which Hindu god Brahma created time and universe. To some, it commemorates the coronation of Rama in Ayodhya after his victory over evil Ravana.

Few people sent me below wishes today:

[image]

**Is there any scriptural evidence which states coronation of Rama on the very first day of Chaitra Navratri (or Yugadi/Ugadi or Gudi Padwa)?**

Comment: Scripture tag is not needed when you post a question about references from scriptures. Identification  request tag is enough. You haven't used in your previous questions too.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Scripture is used to find scriptural reference. Identification request is used to find verse locations or image locations.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I know that. Verse location is same as scriptural references. But using scripture tag for references is way too braod for that tag.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma verse location could be better tag than identification request. Identification request could be used just for images but scripture tag can be used for that purpose.

Comment: @TheDestroyer That would become a very broader tag if it is used for references also. All the questions here are asking scriptural references. Almost all the questions will have the tag if that is allowed.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma With same logic, even identification request can be used to every question, if it allowed. If OP explicitly wants from scriptures only, then we can use it.

Comment: @TheDestroyer ID is for location from scriptures and scripture is for questions about texts. It is clear here. What is explicitly from scriptures and not explicitly from scriptures? They are the same. Aren't they? I feel we should use [chat].

Answer (score 2):

Chaitra Navaratri starts with pAdyami (1st day) of Chaitra month/mAsa.

King Dasaratha wanted to coronate Sri Rama in chaitra month.

> चैत्रः श्रीमानयं मासः पुण्यः पुष्पितकाननः | यौवराज्याय रामस्य
>   सर्वमेवोपकल्प्यताम् || २-३-४ राज्ञस्तूपरते वाक्ये जनघोषो महानभूत् |
>
> "This is the glorious and auspicious month of Chaitra, in which the
>   forests bloom with flowers. Let all arrangements be made for the
>   coronation of Rama as prince." While these words of the king were
>   being completed, there was a great delightful uproar of the people.

---

It was described in Srimad Ramayana that Sri Rama reached the hermitage of the sage Bharadwaja, after exile period, on the fifth (5th) day of lunar month after completion of 14 years of exile.

> पूर्णे चतुर्दशे वर्षे पञ्चम्यां लक्ष्मणाग्रजः | भरद्वाजाश्रमं प्राप्य
>   ववन्दे नियतो मुनिम् || ६-१२४-१
>
> After completion of fourteen years of his exile and on the fifth day of the bright half of the lunar month , Rama, who was disciplined
>   even now, reaching the hermitage of the sage Bharadwaja, offered his
>   salutation to the sage.

---

So Sri Rama's coronation did not take place on the 1st day of Chaitra.